# ReactJs:::Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

```
   5 | const Recipes = props => (
   6 |   <div className="container">
>  7 |     <div className="row">
   8 |      { props.recipes.map((recipe) => {
   9 |        return(
  10 |          <div key={recipe.title} className="col-md-4" style={{ marginBottom:"2rem" }}>
```

Comment: `props.recipes` is `undefined`

Comment: show us your code. What are the values in `recipes` or in `props`

Comment: Not the slightest effort, even in the post content here...

Answer (score 0):

Check that you're passing `recipes` to the component as props correctly.

`Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` means that `props` doesn't contain an object/array/whatever called `recipes`, so when it tries to `map` on something that doesn't exist it doesn't know what to do and falls over.

---

In this example, `recipes` is passed correctly (and it shouldn't fail):

```
const Element = (props) => <div>
  {props.recipes.map(recipe => <p>{recipe}</p>)}
</div>

<Element recipes={["egg", "sausage"]} />
```

In this example, it will fail:

```
const Element = (props) => <div>
  {props.recipes.map(recipe => <p>{recipe}</p>)}
</div>

<Element />
```

There are lots of ways that `recipes` could be undefined. This is just one. You need to check through your code and find where you're expecting to pass `recipes` and see if you're doing so correctly or not.